# Save_model in admin not working in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a trouble with Django.

Models.py:

```
class PlaylistItem(models.Model):
         playlist_name = models.TextField()
         date_created_playlist = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
         author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and my Admin.py :

```
class PlaylistItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['playlist_name','author']
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        print("hello")
        obj.author = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
admin.site.register(PlaylistItem,PlaylistItemAdmin)
```

And in console, it's not printing "hello". But in admin page, it is showing 2 'playlist_name','author', Why is it ?

--Updated my models.py - still not working :

```
class PlaylistItem(models.Model):
      playlist_name = models.TextField()
      date_created_playlist = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
      author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

---updated here---
      def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super(PlaylistItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Because you do not *save* a model? You are only *rendering* objects.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yah, thank you for your reply. I added :"    
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlaylistItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
---in my PlaylistItem(models.Model), but it's still not working :(